# Problem with Method.invoke

Tags: java, reflection, invocation

I have a method that return a list of objects and I want to call it by the invoke method of the class Method. The only problem is that invoke method returns an `Object` and not a `list<Object>`.

The code is here:

```
Class<? extends AnObject> anObject = MyObject.getClass();
Method myMethod = MyObject.getMethod("getListObject"); 
Object objject = method.invoke(MyObject); // I want it to return list
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Class<? extends AnObject>  anObject = MyObject.getClass();
Method myMethod = MyObject.getMethod("getListObject"); 
List object = (List)myMethod.invoke(anObject);
```

Comment: I already did this but i have an exception: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: well, then cast it to `org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet`. If your function doesn't return a list then you can't get a list.

Answer (score 0):

Just typecast it:

```
List list = (List)method.invoke(...);
```

Comment: I already did this but i have an exception: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: then maybe you could try to cast into Set.. are you sure it returns a List?

Comment: PersistentSet class implements a set, not list.

Comment: It works with Set: Set list = (Set)method.invoke(...); thanks

Comment: @user855388 So your method doesn't return a List at all, so your question is wrong. Cast it to *PersistentSet.*

Comment: My method returns a Set. But i thought that a List and a Set are the same because they're both collections. No need to Cast it to PersistentSet, it works with Set.

Comment: @user855388 'a List and a Set are the same because they're both collections'? No, one is a List and the other is a Set. *If you don't care which you get,* cast to a Collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly cast the result to the type you desire.

```
List<?> theList = (List<?>) method.invoke(anObject, new Object[] {})
```

This may result in a `ClassCastException` in runtime if the method doesn't return the type you expected.

Comment: I already did this but i have an exception: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: So your method doesn't return a List. So cast it to PersistentSet.

Answer (score 0):

How about letting [dp4j](http://dp4j.com)'s annotations processor figure it out?

```
@com.dp4j.Reflect //or @org.junit.Test
public void test(){
  Object objject =  MyObject.getListObject();
}
```

You can also print the injected code with `-Averbose=true`.

Answer (score 0):

what let me to this page is

when I tried to invoke a protected method without making it Accessible

take look at my now working version

```
DoPubService service = SpringAdapter.getBean("frontendDoPubService", DoPubService.class);
try {
    Method runUrlReplacerMethod = service.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("runUrlReplacer", String.class, String.class, String.class);

    return runUrlReplacerMethod.invoke(service, "10.21019/qna-900031", "abs", explanation);
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this is not working because the Method should be `Accessible` before `invoking` it

```
runUrlReplacerMethod.setAccessible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 solution:

```
List<?> list = (List) invokeResult;
List<String> = list.stream().map(el -> (String) el).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Change `String` to type you need.